# Accurate CPU usage with Prometheus from WIndows

Tags: monitoring, cpu-usage, metrics, grafana, prometheus

Using the wmi_exporter or the scollector_exporter with Prometheus I am finding it difficult to get accurate CPU usage. Here is the metrics I am using and the query I am using for scollector:

```
os_cpu with returns: 1.54432653e+07
```

I do a query with rate:

```
rate(os_cpu{exported_instance="myHost"}[30s])
```

Here is the graph I have come up with from this query in Grafana[image: Green line is the utilisation]

os_cpu returns a overall CPU usage i.e. all cores, and comparing this with Taskmanager in Windows it does not add up as that shows 100% max. It cannot be possible to get 300% CPU usage.

What can I do with my query to get a more accurate measurement?

Comment: I'm not sure where this os_cpu metric is coming from - wmi_exporter? At any rate, perhaps the best thing to do would be to ask on their github page what the metric means.

Comment: @FuzzyAmi Yep, and I think I got a better metric by using a larger time time range, I dont see spikes inbetween but its a better graph. I used 2m instead of 30s

Answer (score 6):

For now you might have found the answer, but anyway... This seems to be useful:

```
100 - (avg by (instance) (irate(windows_cpu_time_total{mode="idle", instance=~"$server"}[1m])) * 100)
```

from grafana dashboards library: https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/12566

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple cores the usage can go above 100%

I suggest you use
`100 - (avg by (instance) (irate(node_cpu{job="node",mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100)`

Here is a more [detailed blog post](https://www.robustperception.io/understanding-machine-cpu-usage/) about it

Comment: node_cpu is a node exporter parameter and not for windows exporter aka wmi exporter